# Ladder Graph and Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to prove that(By induction and Deletion Contraction Theorem) the following chromatic polynomial holds for all values of n on a ladder graph:
$$(−1)(^2−3+3)^{−1}$$
I have seen some explanations of this in other areas on this site, but none utilize (or properly explain) the use of induction. Additionally, some neglect to explain why it is necessary that $$(^2−3+3)^{−1}$$ needs to be raised to the power of n-1.

Answer (score 1):

**The use of induction**

Assume that the chromatic polynomial of $L_n$ is $(−1)(^2−3+3)^{−1}$. Consider how to extend any $k$-colouring of $L_n$ to the extra two points of $L_{n+1}$.

For definiteness, let the new rung be $a-b$ which is joined to rung $y-z$. Let $a$ be joined to $y$ and $b$ joined to $z$.

**Case 1** If $a$ is coloured the same as $z$.

Then there are $k-1$ choices for $b$.

**Case 2** If $a$ is not coloured the same as $z$.

Then there are $k-2$ choices for $a$ and a further $k-2$ choices for $b$.

The total number of $k$-colourings is now

$(−1)(^2−3+3)^{−1}$ multiplied by $(k-1)+(k-2)^2=^2−3+3$.

I hope this makes the induction and the $^2−3+3$ term easier to understand.

Comment: I'm sorry, i've been up for 36 hours straight so i'm not at peak mental performance, but can you explain which edge you contract? and how to use deletion contraction in the proof?

Comment: I have not formally used the techniques you mention since there was no need and I hoped this answer would help you see how induction is used. However, if you think about the meaning of those techniques you will see the connection. As far as colouring is concerned:-colouring $a$ and $z$ the same has the same effect as making them the same point. Colouring $a$ and $z$ differently has the same effect as considering them to be joined.

Comment: is case one your "base case"?

Comment: also, why did you multiply (−1)(2−3+3)^−1 by(−1)+(−2)^2 and how does them being equal to k^2-3k+3 indicate a proof?

Comment: No. The 'base case' in an inductive proof is the 'smallest' case of the result to be proved. For your problem it would be $L_1$

Comment: wait, ignore my last comment lol. Stll, dont we need a base case?

Comment: For each of the $(−1)(^2−3+3)^{−1}$ ways of colouring the ladder $L_n$ there are $(k-1)+(k-2)^2=^2−3+3$ ways of extending the colouring. Therefore you multiply these two expressions.

Comment: oh okay okay that makes sense

Comment: Thank you so so much for your help, I thnk i understand :)

Comment: Glad to have helped.